# Keeping Multidimensional Array's Semantic?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, syntax

Today's the first day I've really gotten stuck into creating anything from scratch in PHP7. My script skills are pretty rudimentary anyway, so I apologise in advance.

I've been looking at tutorial pages + searching Google/Stack and can't seem to find the answer to a few basic syntax questions about Multidimensional Arrays (MDAs).

The tutorials I've read show MDAs as follows:

### MDA Tutorial Example:

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

```
$a = array(array(array("a", a2, a3),
                 array("b", b2, b3),
                 array("c", c2, c3) 
                 ),
           array(array("a", a2, a3),
                 array("b", b2, b3),
                 array("c", c2, c3) 
                 ),
           array(array("a", a2, a3),
                 array("b", b2, b3),
                 array("c", c2, c3) 
                 )
           );
```

As all the layers are simply named ***array*** and [W3 only calls the parent variable with numerical values](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_multi) for **[$row] [$col]** it's unclear what solutions there are for naming and labeling elements in the array with custom handles.

[Example 6 on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) shows something that looks along the right lines, but it's not an exact demonstration.

Using the array shorthand which I'm more familiar with, would something like this work?

### For Example:

```
    $a = [Custom1[Custom2[Custom3["a", a2, a3],
                         Custom3["b", b2, b3],
                         Custom3["c", c2, c3] 
                         ],
    //**does each level require the same naming as the level above
                 Custom2[Custom3["a", a2, a3],
                         Custom3["b", b2, b3],
                         Custom3["c", c2, c3] 
                         ],
    //**Or Are they independent and customised freely            
                    Fred[Wez["a", a2, a3],
                         Otto["b", b2, b3],
                         Sam["c", c2, c3] 
                         ]],
                   ];
```

> I'm sure this is a fairly basic question, but as I said, I just couldn't seem to find an answer.

Comment: None of the layers are ___named___ "array"... [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) is the function used to create an array.... now PHP also supports "short array syntax"

Comment: Thank you, pretty much had realised that after I'd spent an hour writing it, but still not certain on best solution for creating a semantic way of calling elements across arrays. So I've Rethought the question a bit to make it more along those lines.

Comment: If you want to create an associative array, rather than an enumerated one, then you assign the key as well as the value (as a string)... the main restriction is that the key must be unique within that array

Comment: Consider OOP if you are seeking graceful representation of data

Comment: Not sure what your question/problem is, it's too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept you are looking for is simply "associative arrays".

You could create something like this (trying to use your example).

```
$a = [
    'Custom1' => [
        'Fred' => [
            'Wez' => ["a", a2, a3],
            'Otto' => ["b", b2, b3],
            'Sam' => ["c", c2, c3]
        ]
    ]
];
```

To access to an element here you have to do it this way:

```
$element = $a['Custom1']['Fred']['Otto'][2]; // Last array is numeric
// Now $element has b3.
```

Remember you can't use the same index more than one time into each array.
So you couldn't do this:

```
$a = [
    'Custom1' => [
        'Custom2' => [],
        'Custom2' => []
    ]
];
```

Here you can read more about [php arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Also, as said in comments, array() is just a function you use to create the array, but your are not naming it in any way.
Since PHP 5.4, you can use [] notation, which I in my opinion, keeps the code cleaner.

Comment: That's what I was  looking for thank you for clearing that up. 

I read that post on PHP you linked to, I even linked to it in this post. But I find their guides skim over too much that unless you already understand 90% of what's on the page it's difficult to follow and sometimes the examples are too simplified. Personally I find it much easier to grasp a concept when I can see it's practical application if that make sense. Anyway thanks again :)